# Requirements for enabling compress and aggregation files

Tags: 7, css-js-aggregation

Is there any requirement or module that I need to enable in Apache to properly use the option bandwidth optimization in performance?

Do I need to enable the deflate module or I just need the headers module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

headers module is all you should need